# Load image from URI as layout background

Tags: android, picasso

I have used [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) to load an image from my company's CDN into a `ImageView`:

```
ImageView imgView;
//...
Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(url)).into(imgView);
```

But now I need load an image as a layout background:

```
RelativeLayout theLayout;
//...
Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(url)).into(...);
```

Is it possible with Picasso? If not, should I use a `ImageView` instead of `Relativelayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(your url).into(new Target(){

  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom from) {
     yourlayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
  }
```

edit:

you may need to override following methods as well

```
@Override
  public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
      Log.e("TAG", "Failed");
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      Log.e("TAG", "Prepare Load");
  }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

you can use glide to download bitmap and set it as background from any layout.

```
Glide
        .with(getApplicationContext())
        .load("https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
        .asBitmap()
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
              Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
             theLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
                  // Possibly runOnUiThread()
            }
        });
```

but the better way is to use `imageView` on top of `relativelayout` and make it `match_parent` and show image on this imageview. this will help you directly use glide or picaso to load image in image view without memory errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I really need to use PIcasso. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Picasso for this. Please check following code :

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse(url)).into(new Target(){

  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom from) {
     relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
      Log.d("TAG", "FAILED");
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      Log.d("TAG", "Prepare Load");
  }      
})
```